# KieBuilderImpl.buildAll fails with NullPointerException

Tags: java, apache-spark, drools

I have been struggling since many days to resolve the below `NullPointerException`. are there any configuration that I am missing?

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.kie.internal.io.ResourceFactory.newByteArrayResource(ResourceFactory.java:66)
        at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.AbstractKieModule.getResource(AbstractKieModule.java:303)
        at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.AbstractKieModule.addResourceToCompiler(AbstractKieModule.java:268)
        at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.AbstractKieModule.addResourceToCompiler(AbstractKieModule.java:263)
        at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.AbstractKieProject.buildKnowledgePackages(AbstractKieProject.java:243)
        at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.AbstractKieProject.verify(AbstractKieProject.java:74)
        at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieBuilderImpl.buildKieProject(KieBuilderImpl.java:353)
        at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieBuilderImpl.buildAll(KieBuilderImpl.java:265)
        at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieBuilderImpl.buildAll(KieBuilderImpl.java:209)
```

Below are steps I am following, program fails at `kieBuilder.buildAll()` line:

```
           KieServices kieServices = KieServices.Factory.get();
            KieResources kieResources = kieServices.getResources();
            KieFileSystem kfs = kieServices.newKieFileSystem();
            KieRepository kr = kieServices.getRepository();
 Resource res = kieResources.newByteArrayResource(drlFile.getBytes()).setResourceType(ResourceType.DRL).setSourcePath("test.drl");

kfs.write(res);

 KieBuilder kieBuilder = kieServices.newKieBuilder(kfs,this.getClass().getClassLoader());
            kieBuilder.buildAll();
```

Maven dependency:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
        <artifactId>drools-core</artifactId>
        <version>7.7.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
        <artifactId>drools-compiler</artifactId>
        <version>7.7.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

Thanks! Appreicate your help.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error, It was due to some of the KieServices where not getting initialized. The services are read from kie.conf property file and the above error is due to ResourceFactory Service not being initialized, add **"org.kie.api.io.KieResources = org.drools.core.io.impl.ResourceFactoryServiceImpl"** in your **kie.conf** file to initialize this Service.

Answer (score 0):

We found that this issue comes when kie.conf in 7.X series Drools, when you are creating a fat jar , eg: using shadowJar task in gradle, the kie.conf file does not get merged.

The way to resolve it is update the shadowJar task:

```
 apply plugin: 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow'
shadowJar {
    zip64 true
    mergeServiceFiles {
        path = 'META-INF'
    }

}
```